# 2 different implementations of the API JPA

Tags: jpa

I have an applicatinon whose persistence layer uses EclipseLink, and I want to add some solutions given by Hibernate.
so my question is:
is it possible to use 2 different implementations of JPA in one application ?

Comment: No  that is not possible.

Comment: if you have one persistence unit for implementation 1 (EMF1), a different persistence unit for implementation 2 (EMF2) then there should be no reason why not ... one of the reasons why you can specify the "provider" against each persistence unit. Whether you would be *sane* to do so is a different question ...